# What are the minimum user permissions required to install a Windows service?

Tags: windows, installation, permissions, services

What are the minimum user permissions required to install a Windows service?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Administrative privileges for security reasons.

Only processes with Administrative privileges are able to open handles to the SCM (Service Control Manager) that can be used by the CreateService and LockServiceDatabase functions (see the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981%28VS.85%29.aspx) for details). In the article, you'll see that, for permissions to create a service you need the access right `SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE (0x0002)`, which is included in the generic access right, `GENERIC_WRITE`. If you look a little further down the page, you'll see that **only Administrators** have access to this through `SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS`. The same goes for using InstallUtil.exe to install a .NET Windows service, as InstallUtil calls the native [CreateService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682450%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

An application installing a service would go through one of the two methods. It sounds like a very logical design which prevents security issues, as explained [here](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/topic55462.aspx):

> Actually, this design in Windows makes
>   sense. It is the result of security
>   consideration. Windows Service
>   normally runs under a high privilege
>   account, if a normal account can
>   install an unknown service, it is easy
>   for the malicious user to elevate his
>   privilege. For example, he can use
>   installutil.exe to install a hack
>   service which runs under Local Service
>   account. Then, when the service runs
>   the entire machine will be controlled
>   by the hacker with normal user
>   account. This is really a security
>   hole. So Windows only allows
>   Administrators to install a service.